# How can i run raspberry pi terminal commands from website?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I am making a home automation system with a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino. I am hosting a simple HTML website on the pi with some buttons and indicators. I have already connected the Arduino to PI via UART (Tx,Rx) and I can send a byte/string to the Arduino with command `echo [data] > ttyAMA0`.
Now I would like to ask how can execute a command on the Pi's terminal from the website - let's say when I press one of the buttons I would like to send a command `echo A1 > ttyAMA0` to the Arduino.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. My answer fits for the two ways I am understanding it. How is your Raspberry Pi running a web server (which one?)

Comment: Also, Pi using nginx or apache? I'm assuming apache to host the html.
So far a great start, but you plan to use web page as main interface for all users to access from within your wifi?

Comment: Yes I am using apache. OnIy I will be able to visit the web page. I have a seperate LAN (Just one comp. an Pi)

Answer (score 1):

You might make your program a dedicated web server (you don't always need to install a generic web server program like Apache or Lighttpd on a Rasberry Pi).

In particular, you could code your own C program and use the [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) HTTP web server library in it. This libonion has an [examples/oterm/](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/tree/master/examples/oterm) subdirectory doing exactly what you want (giving some Web interface providing a terminal -visible in a browser using HTML5 & AJAX techniques- with a shell). And you could code your `libonion` program with some web handlers doing some IO (with `fprintf` & `fflush`) to your Arduino board. But be aware of security issues.

Also, web servers can use [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) or [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) techniques to run external programs. If running a generic Apache or Ligghtd you can configure it wisely to enable and use CGI or FastCGI programs.